SR 6e: How Does a Rigger Deal with Cameras
How Does a Solo Rigger Deal with Cameras?
I just got the Shadowrun 6e book, and I was theory-crafting characters of different archetypes through some simple scenarios to get a feel for them.
It seems pretty straightforward for a Mage, Technomancer, or Decker to sneak passed a camera - they just magic it or hack it.
A Face or Spy type can steal the right uniform and just walk passed the camera acting like they belong there. (which may not work, but at least it's something)
Street Samurai are either going to avoid the camera or do a smash and grab, but honestly, that seems to fit the archetype.
Riggers feel like a utility archetype, and they indeed have a good ability to find the cameras using microdrones that look like bugs. But once they've located the issue, they don't seem to have great options.
My thoughts so far where:

Smash it with a drone (expensive and obvious)
Hack it (cyberdecks are expensive, and this steps on the Decker's toes)
Find the guy monitoring the camera feed, and then send the bug drone to knock them out with a toxin (which seems like a good answer, but also seems way more involved then just saying "I cast Improved Invisibility and walk passed it.")

So - other than "get a crew, chummer" - how does a Rigger deal with a camera?

Don't bother to disable it
If you can fly a drone or microdrone to the camera undetected to destroy it, why even bother? Just fly the microdrone past the camera and continue on.
Alternatives
You might also be able to rig vehicles that belong to the organization that installed the camera so they are unsuspicious and can just drive by in full view. Drive that cleaning or maintenance robot to where you want it. (You will need however to first get access to them to mod them with a rigger adaption).
The rules also say

Where a decker can control something remotely through a host, a rigger takes it a step further, using their augmentations and specialized equipment
to merge their consciousness with a device, be it a drone, vehicle, or in some cases an entire building. [p. 196]

However, there is pretty scant support for actually "driving" an entire building with its IT infrastructure. Nearly all the rules only discuss rigging drones or vehicles.
Rely on your team
Keep in mind that the default assumption for the game is that you have a team of runners. Not every archetype will be able (nor should they) to cover all challenges equally well. There is a reason you get a team together, so their skills can compelemnt each other.

I figured the answer was "ask your Decker" -- It just feels weird that I can't get my meatspace body passed a camera without help as a rigger; I like the maintenance robot idea. A big floor waxing machine could at least let me attempt to hide behind it for a stealth check.
